# reading classical ini file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ini

does anybody knows how to parse an ini file ? I guess I need a regular expression or something.

I have only this pattern in the file :

varName=value;

Thanks a lot !

update : here you go : https://github.com/DrMoriarty/MetroEditor/tree/master/MetroEditor/ini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an INI file parser written in objective C available <strike>[here](http://marm.homepage.t-online.de/)</strike> - either use it directly, or read the source to pick up a few tips.

EDIT: as that link appears dead, try [this alternative](https://github.com/DrMoriarty/MetroEditor/tree/master/MetroEditor/ini) - thanks mc007

Comment: The url is broken now :(

Comment: found a copy here : https://github.com/DrMoriarty/MetroEditor/tree/master/MetroEditor/ini